# How to access the database of other website?

Tags: php

I'm new to PHP coding. I'm having problem to access the database of other website from one of mine.

Actually I've my website as www.mysite.com and I need to access database of the external website for example www.external.com and this database will be stroed into mine..

Steps to be proceed:

1) Access the database of www.external.com

2) The data is need to be store in my site www.mysite.com

What should I do know???

Thanks in advance,

Sandra

Comment: Just create a new php file for example external_connection.php and setup your external connection in this file.

Comment: When you want to get data from external include external_connection.php file.

Answer (score 0):

This is normally not possible because of security.  If you post the data to second site, and give it permission, it would work, but if you do not own both sites, this is not possible.

Comment: Thank you for your valuable answer